# How do you convert between Substrate specific types and Rust primitive types?

Tags: safe-math

Using the Substrate blockchain framework, how can I convert between Substrate specific types and Rust primitive types and vice versa?

For example:

- Convert a time (`T::Moment`) to a `u64`
- Convert a u64 to a `T::Balance`

etc...

Original: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56081117/how-do-you-convert-between-substrate-specific-types-and-rust-primitive-types

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For most Substrate specific types like `BlockNumber`, `Balance`, `Nonce`, etc... we guarentee that these types use a `u32` with the [`AtLeast32Bit`](https://crates.parity.io/sp_arithmetic/traits/trait.AtLeast32Bit.html) trait.

From the trait [`BaseArithmetic`](https://crates.parity.io/sp_arithmetic/traits/trait.BaseArithmetic.html), the following are implemented:

- `From`: `u8`, `u16`, `u32`
- `TryFrom`: `u64`, `u128`, `usize`
- `TryInto`: `u8`, `u16`, `u32`, `u64`, `u128`, `usize`

Another trait is also provided to provide ergonomic
infallible conversion when you don't care if the value saturates.

- `UniqueSaturatedInto`: `u8`, `u16`, `u32`, `u64`, `u128`
- `UniqueSaturatedFrom`: `u64`, `u128`

> **NOTE on `SaturatedConversion`**
>
> `SaturatedConversion` (`saturated_into` and `saturated_from`) should not be used unless you know what you're doing, you've thought and considered all options and your use-case implies that saturation is fundamentally correct. The only time I imagine this is the case is deep in runtime arithmetic where you are logically certain it will not overflow, but can't provide a proof because it would depend on consistent pre-existing state.

This means that working from `u32` to Substrate specific types should be easy:

```
pub fn u32_to_balance(input: u32) -> T::Balance {
    input.into()
}
```

For larger types, you need to handle the case where the `Balance` type for a runtime is smaller than what is available:

```
pub fn u64_to_balance_option(input: u64) -> Option<T::Balance> {
    input.try_into().ok()
}

// Note the warning above about saturated conversions
pub fn u64_to_balance_saturated(input: u64) -> T::Balance {
    input.saturated_into()
}
```

When converting from `T::Balance` to a rust primitive, you need to also handle conversion between incompatible types:

```
pub fn balance_to_u64(input: T::Balance) -> Option<u64> {
    TryInto::<u64>::try_into(input).ok()
}

// Note the warning above about saturated conversions
pub fn balance_to_u64_saturated(input: T::Balance) -> u64 {
    input.saturated_into::<u64>()
}
```