# How to convert substrate Specific Types(Option<BalanceOf<T>> ) to Rust Primitive types (U64)?

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrateinterface, rust-ipfs

I don't know how can I convert Option<BalanceOf> (subtrate specific type)to u64 (rust primitive types)?

I followed this article( [How do you convert between Substrate specific types and Rust primitive types?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/13/how-do-you-convert-between-substrate-specific-types-and-rust-primitive-types) ), it helped me while converting u64 to Option<BalanceOf using the below function.

```
    pub fn u64_to_balance_option(input: u8) -> Option<BalanceOf<T>> {
            input.try_into().ok()
        }
```

But I also need to convert some Option<BalanceOf> types inside u64 to perform some mathematical operation and then again convert u64 to Option<BalanceOf> to put back inside my storage items.

Thank you

Comment: Can you share the function signature you want, since your question makes exactly what types you are working with confusing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll see that `Currency::Balance` is bound to `AtLeast32BitUnsigned` which by being bound to `BaseArithmetic` is bound to implement `TryInto<u64>`. Therefore the most obvious code is something like:

```
pub fn balance_to_u64_option(input: impl TryInto<u64>) -> Option<u64> {
    input.try_into().ok()
}
```

However, balances cannot necessarily be expressed as a `u64`, so this really isn't such a great plan for production code as it will restrict your pallet to being used only when someone has a small enough balance.

In general, you should aim to do all arithmetic in the native Polkadot types. `Currency::Balance` is required to implement all the typical arithmetic operations for this reason.

Comment: Can you please make it more simple for me, I am very new  to substrate and rust, 

Thank you for your response.